# TP-link TL-WN725N USB wifi adaptor is not detected on Ubuntu 20.04 server OS

Tags: 20.04, tp-link

I have tried this https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu in my new PC (Plugged my dongle into MSI b450M board USB) But no luck. Still the WiFi dongle was not detected and no green light blink happens.

**Note:** Wifi dongle is working fine with Windows Laptop. WiFi dongle not detected mainly in server OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: I m using ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64. The above solution works for desktop with GUI ubuntu 20. But in my case its's ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64 where it's not detecting the USB WiFi dongle even I have connected to motherboard directly. Tried in all ports but no luck.